# XML parsing iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing

I am having this string:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:methods" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="urn:PingdomAPI" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:createAccountResponse><return xsi:type="ns2:CreateAccountResponse"><status xsi:type="xsd:int">3</status><password xsi:nil="true"/></return></ns1:createAccountResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The question is: How to extract int value of 3, the value for status.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (or a third party solution).
See [this blog post of mine](http://www.levelofindirection.com/journal/2009/9/24/elegant-xml-parsing-with-objective-c.html) for some more info and a useful wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

These examples are taken from Apple's e[vent driven XML programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.pdf).

Creating and initializing a NSXMLParser instance:

```
BOOL success;
NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToFile];
if (addressParser) // addressParser is an NSXMLParser instance variable
    [addressParser release];
addressParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
[addressParser setDelegate:self];
[addressParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
success = [addressParser parse]; // return value not used
            // if not successful, delegate is informed of error
```

Implement the delegation methods that are of interest to you.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

For a full list of delegate methods see [NSXMLParser Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/NSXMLParser_Class.pdf).

Comment: NSXML is available only in simulator, but not on the device itself due to performance issues

Comment: You are correct, MLaden, but rjstelling's example uses NSXMLParser, which *is* available on the device.

Comment: How would I implement this to my problem. I suggest that I would init addressParser with contents of a string instead of URL. But how to extract that int value for key "status"?

Comment: Mladen you need to implement didStartElement: and parse:foundCharacters: You really need to read the docs (and/ or my blog post). There's not too much to it. We can help you with specific issues you might have.